# MySQL - retrieve many rows and count affected rows in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run a simple query with a WHERE statement, returning only some columns, like this:

```
SELECT var1, var2 FROM table WHERE key=1
```

This runs as expected and returns many rows. However, I actually want to retrieve both all the matching rows *and* count the affected rows. But if I try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, var1, var2 FROM table WHERE key=1
```

I get the count and only the first row.

Is it possible to get both many rows and count the affected rows in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it via subquery to get the number of total records

```
SELECT var1, var2, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE columnName = 1) AS `COUNT`
FROM   tableName
WHERE  columnName = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a tool specifically for this. Add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to your statement like so:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS var1, var2 FROM table WHERE key=1
```

And then you can get your count using `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`

**This count ignores the `LIMIT` clause in your original statement!**

Also, it has to be executed sequentially. If you wait too long, another `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` might overwrite your previous count.

*Edit: Sorry, this is not in one query. This is more efficient than subqueries though.*

*P.S.: Actually, why not simply count() the results in php after your retrieve the data for the actual count?*